# debug.log file size

Tags: client

According to [this comment](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=8989.msg130821#msg130821), the debug.log file in the Bitcoin application data directory should be truncated on startup if it is bigger than 10MB. I'm running Bitcoin 0.5.2 on Windows 7 and it does no such thing - the file keeps increasing in size even after restarts, and it is already over 1GB.

Why is it not truncated? Is it safe to stop Bitcoin and truncate the file manually, or delete it completely?

Answer (score 2):

bitcoind 0.5.99-beta was running and my debug.log was 26MB.  After

```
bitcoind stop
(wait 30 sec. or so for stop)
bitcoind -daemon
```

debug.log was 201KB.

Mac OS 10.6.7

Comment: my debug.log became 4GB. There should be awareness to truncate debug.log even as the software is running not upon restart

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and deleted the file. There don't seem to be any side effects.